# Is there anyway to get satellite image based on coordinates and date filter from Google Earth Engine using Python?

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-python-api

I have tried many ways to get the image based on the date. I copied code from the documentation of GEE but the issue is that the resulting image is not High Definition and if I zoom in on the image, it gets blurred. The code is following:

```
import ee
import geemap

# Initialize the Google Earth Engine Python API.
#ee.Authenticate()
ee.Initialize()
dataset = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC09/C02/T1_L2').filterDate(
    '2022-01-01', '2022-02-01'
)


# Applies scaling factors.
def apply_scale_factors(image):
  optical_bands = image.select('SR_B.').multiply(0.0000275).add(-0.2)
  thermal_bands = image.select('ST_B.*').multiply(0.00341802).add(149.0)
  return image.addBands(optical_bands, None, True).addBands(
      thermal_bands, None, True
  )


dataset = dataset.map(apply_scale_factors)

visualization = {
    'bands': ['SR_B4', 'SR_B3', 'SR_B2'],
    'min': 0.0,
    'max': 0.3,
}

m = geemap.Map()
m.set_center(67.0011,24.8607, 10)
m.add_layer(dataset, visualization, 'True Color (432)')
m
```

My task is to get the image in realtime and based on date filter. Even If change the dates, I always get the same satellite image, instead of past ones.

Comment: I'm unable to replicate this. It renders fine, clearly show the 30m pixels when zooming in. Changing date range also give different imagery.

Comment: @DanielWiell when the image is rendered and I try to zoom in, the image(pixels) gets brownish color. My basic task is to get high-definition imagery through which I can easily identify the cars on the streets and for the same coordinate I need old imagery as well. Is it possible through GEE API? Is there any other way for it? Because its not working in my case.

Comment: The resolution of optical bands in Landsat images is 30m. To identify cars on the streets you should be looking for much higher-resolution images. It's more likely that you will find them through commercial solutions. Anyway, this is already unrelated to the original question.